# What happens when error occurs during cdo?

Tags: vimscript, repeated-commands

:h :cdo says:

```
            When an error is detected execution stops.
            The last buffer (or where an error occurred) becomes
            the current buffer.
```

Let's see what really happens:

Prepare test file `a`:

```
dog0 dog1
dog2 dog3
```

Prepare test file `b`:

```
dog4 dog5
dog6 dog7
```

set up quickfix for all dogs :

```
vimgrep /dog\d/g a b
```

Create a test command:

```
" call cdo to change dog to cat, throw an error in the first n entries
command! -nargs=1 TestCdo call Test(<q-args>)

function! Test(error_count)
  let s:error_count = a:error_count
  let s:error_index = 0

  " restore a b
  cdo e!

  cdo call s:test_impl()
endfunction

function! s:test_impl()
  if s:error_index < s:error_count
    let s:error_index += 1
    throw 1
  endif
  norm! c3lcat
endfunction
```

Test result:

```
Test        dogs     cats
---------------------------
TestCdo 1   dog0     cat1-7
TestCdo 2   dog0-1   cat2-7
TestCdo 3   dog0-2   cat3-7
TestCdo 4   dog0-7
TestCdo 5   dog0-7
TestCdo 6   dog0-7
TestCdo 7   dog0-7
TestCdo 8   dog0-7
```

It looks like `cdo` stops only if `dog3` throws an error, `dog3` is the last `entry` in `a`, <s>**does that mean `cdo` only stops if last entry in a buffer cause an error**?</s> That's very disturbing, especially if you have hundreds of files to deal with. Is this a bug?

I know you can create `macro` such as `qp@q:cnext<cr>q` to make it stop at first error, this question is not about that.

I'm using `vim8.1-2127` on `ubuntu16.04`.

**Update0**

@Ralf's comment shows that `cdo` may continue to next buffer if all entries in a buffer throws an error.

**Update1**

@[D.Ben.Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) filed a [bug report](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5102).

Comment: I just tested `:cdo echo x` and Vim printed `E121: Undefined variable: x` for every entry in the qf list. I expected it to stop after the first error.  Either I'm totally misinterpreting the docs or it is a bug.

Comment: @Ralf Just tried your `:cdo echo x`, I thout it would stop after the first 4 errors, but it didn't, which makes it even more mysterious.

Comment: Exactly, but why throw on the first count entries? I would have expected to throw once, at the given index. I realize now your comment says error in the first n, but why? How is that measuring what you want? You might also want to try with only a single error at position n, and also use the input 0. That could help give a more complete picture of whats happening. Also, using :debug could help trace the execution better. To your bold q: your tests for 4+ prove that cdo did not stop every time the last entry in a buffer causes an error.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The doc says `cdo` stops if an error is detected, my goal is 
 to prove it doesn't, the bold conclusion is in fact a question, there is a `?` after it, as i don't have solid prove, it's just an observation, Ralf's comment already shows that my conclusion is wrong. Sorry if my test examples give you confusion.

Comment: I understand your goal, but your test seems far too complicated. Ralf's is simpler, and there are others. Again, I'm not sure why throwing n errors is better than throwing 1 or all, but I'll leave that be; perhaps I've just misunderstood. Please re-read my comment, where I state `To your bold q:`—I was attempting to answer your question, using an observation about your results. They give effective proof that the claim in the q is false. You might want to check `:TestCdo 0`, as I said, or try with only a single error (instead of many). Try with `:debug`. Then file a bug report.

Comment: bug report filed https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5102

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The tests for 4 and 4+ shows that all dogs in `b` is not changed, it doesn't conflict with my observation. I just tried to throw 1 instead of n, the result didn't conflict with my observation too, only throw in `dog3` can stop `cdo` from continue to `b`, only throw in `dog3` can save `dog4-7` from being changed to `cat4-7`

Comment: @dedowsdi agh, i got mixed up again. I see how your tests indicate something relating to the last error in a buffer. But still, that shouldnt be expected. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  There is a [patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/eQCTUtHZV6k/LA6Am9dhAQAJ) available for testing. It was send to the vimdev mailing list and didn't make it to github.

Comment: All: I've tested the patch and it gives more `global`-like behavior